# Pod anti-affinity and re-balancing pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment with 2 replicas. I would like to specify that, when possible, pods should be load balanced between as many nodes/hostnames. So far, I have the following spec:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: topspin-apollo-backend-staging-dep
  labels:
    app: topspin-apollo-backend
    env: staging
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: topspin-apollo-backend
      env: staging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: topspin-apollo-backend
        env: staging
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: topspin-apollo-backend
          image: rwu1997/topspin-apollo-backend:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: topspin-apollo-backend-staging-secrets
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app: topspin-apollo-backend
                    env: staging
                topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

If I `kubectl apply` this deployment from scratch, k8s correctly schedules a pod on each of the 2 nodes in the cluster (A and B). If I kill one of the nodes B, the corresponding pod is re-scheduled on the last remaining node A (as expected).

When I re-add another node C back to the cluster, the two pods remain scheduled on node A. This is expected as far as I know.

Is there a way to trigger the scheduler to re-balance the 2 pods amongst node A and C?

I've tried `kubectl scale --replicas=4`, have two additional pods scheduled on node C, then `kubectl scale --replicas=2`, but it seems to kill off the 2 most recently scheduled pods (instead of prioritizing the pod anti-affinity).

One method that works is to `kubectl delete` the deployment then `kubectl apply`, but this introduces downtime.

Another method is to `kubectl scale --replicas=1`, then `kubectl scale --replicas=2`, but it's less than ideal since there exists only 1 replica for a period of time.

Comment: you could delete the replicaset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use [descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler). Along with few other use cases, one thing which it helps with is scenarios where pod/node affinity requirements are not satisfied anymore due to changes in the cluster.

The descheduler can be run as a Job or CronJob inside of a k8s cluster. It supports a few strategies and in your case, `RemoveDuplicates` strategy should be helpful. It's fairly straightforward to use. Have a look at the docs and the example configuration https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler#removeduplicates

Comment: interesting one!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this scenario including one more scenarios where sometimes I want to move the single pod to another Node (due to resource requirement). I normally follow this-

```
   kubectl cordon <NODE>
   #delete pod on this NODE
   kubectl delete pod <pod name>
   # once the pod is created on another node.
   kubectl uncrodon <NODE>
```

For single pods, I do scaling of deployment after cordon of NODE to avoid any downtime for that service. you can try this.